# Javascript : How to get a count of same objects in an array?

Tags: javascript, json

Here is my json object. In which i'm storing the object Id & type of object.

```
let jsonData = [
   {"id": "1", "object": "pen"}, 
   {"id": "4", "object": "bag"}, 
   {"id": "2", "object": "paper"}, 
   {"id": "5", "object": "bottle"},
   {"id": "3", "object": "notepad"}, 
   {"id": "1", "object": "pen"}, 
   {"id": "4", "object": "bag"}, 
   {"id": "3", "object": "notepad"}, 
   {"id": "3", "object": "notepad"}, 
   {"id": "1", "object": "pen"}, 
   {"id": "2", "object": "paper"},
   {"id": "1", "object": "pen"},      
]
```

So, now i want to create a new array using above array in below format:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Object       |        Unit      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         Pen         |         4        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         Paper       |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Notepad      |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         Bag         |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Bottle       |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

In short new array should display all object with their count values.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function

```js
 let jsonData = [
      {"id": "1", "object": "pen"}, 
      {"id": "4", "object": "bag"}, 
      {"id": "2", "object": "paper"}, 
      {"id": "5", "object": "bottle"},
      {"id": "3", "object": "notepad"}, 
      {"id": "1", "object": "pen"}, 
      {"id": "4", "object": "bag"}, 
      {"id": "3", "object": "notepad"}, 
      {"id": "3", "object": "notepad"}, 
      {"id": "1", "object": "pen"}, 
      {"id": "2", "object": "paper"},
      {"id": "1", "object": "pen"},      
   ];

   let summary = jsonData.reduce( (ac, el) => {

    let obj = ac.find(e => e.object == el.object);

    if (!obj) {
      obj = {object: el.object, unit: 0};
      ac.push(obj);
    }

    obj.unit = obj.unit + 1;
    return ac;
   }, []);
   
   console.log(summary);
```